# exe won't terminate in Java using Process

Tags: java, c++, process

In my Java program I run `foo.exe` using following statement :

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("foo.exe", parameter1,parameter2).start();
process.waitFor();
```

and in my `foo.exe` it was written in C++ as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //some statement

    return 0;
}
```

however from task manager, the `foo.exe` won't terminate and my java program is hanging at `waitFor()` statement. I tried changing `return 0` to `exit(0)` with no luck.

I have to manually end `foo.exe` through task manager to make my java continue running. Is there any other solution ?

**Edit:** if i comment out `process.waitFor()` , `foo.exe` does terminate properly. However Java wont wait for `foo.exe` to finish its execution first which is not I expected.

Comment: You may need to consume the processes output/error streams.  I'd also consider using a `ProcessBuilder` instead, as this will allow you to redirect the error stream into the input stream and consume them in a single step.  Even if you don't care about the output, this might be required in order to allow the process to terminate and/or run properly

Comment: I suppose it depends on `// some statement` in the exe. Are you sure that code is executing to completion and not hanging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I figured it out.</strike>

At first I don't understand MadProgrammer's hint, his reply precisely point out the cause of problem :

> some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard
>   input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream
>   or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess
>   to block, and even deadlock.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("foo.exe",parameter1,parameter2);
//process.waitFor();

Process p = pb.start();
int result = p.waitFor(); // i guess this is the way
```

thank you so much MadProgrammer and jaco0646

Comment: Please add the source of the quote.